# vb.net event on tabpage shown

Tags: vb.net, tabs

Is it possible to have an event fire off when a certain tabpage of a tabcontrol is active?

I would like to kick off a timer when one of my pages is shown.
I would also like to stop said timer when that page is no longer active.

any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: start by examining the wide selection of events available in the TabControl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `tabPage.Enter` and `tabPage.Leave` events

`Control.Enter` Event Occurs when the control is entered.

`Control.Leave` Event Occurs when the input focus leaves the control.

Comment: You little beauty! thats exactly what i was after!